# Schedule Windows 10 to create restore points and keep only last X number of points

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I would like to schedule my PC to create a restore point every 24 hours, and only keep the last 7 days worth of these automatically created restore points.

I can configure the `SR` task in `Task Scheduler` to create a restore point every 24 hours, but as far as I can tell this will just accumulate restore points indefinitely.

Is there a way to achieve a limited continuous restore point schedule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know how to create Restore points, here is how to delete them
selectively using a PowerShell script.

```
#delete all System Restore Points older than 7 days 
$removeDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ComputerRestorePoint |
        Where { $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime) -lt  $removeDate } |  
        Delete-ComputerRestorePoint
```

Comment: thanks I am now using this, it was helpful.  But what I found was that I changed this to AddDays(-30)  but  microsoft is also somewhere deleting my restore points without my permission.  do you know where?  I can only see 1 restore point. all my latest 30 days of restore were also deleted somehow by windows.  is there a regedit or task scheduler somewhere that I can delete?

Comment: I found this.. but I don't know where the maintenance task is? and why did microsoft make a spelling mistake in the word 'maintenance'  where is the coder review at microsoft on this stuff.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore\LastMainenanceTaskRunTimeStamp

Answer (score 1):

You limit the drive space that System Restore can use in the same window that you manage the system restore settings. Just set a percentage and forget it.

[System Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS2zP.png)

Comment: This would not work, because the percentage setting from the system properties under system restore is ignored by windows.